# How to compare li data-target value and get span text in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to compare `li data-target` value and get span text in jquery
For example:-

```
var sample = 'test@gmail.com';

var text = $("ul#list li data-target "+ sample +" span").text();
console.log(text);
```

above the code am using yet not get span value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the attribute selector and append the `sample` variable correctly. Try this:

```
var sample = 'test@gmail.com';
var text = $('ul#list li [data-target="' + sample + '"] span').text();
console.log(text);
```

Comment: hi sir, i have one more doubt is it possible for same as compare id ex: var sample = 'test%20group@gmail.com'. var text = $('ul#list li#'+sample+' span').text();
console.log(text);

Comment: That would work fine - assuming you're using HTML5. In XHTML the id would not be valid due to the `@` character.

Comment: ok sir, suppose var sample = 'test%20group-gmail-com'. var text = $('ul#list li#'+sample+' span').text(); console.log(text); am try to use this also but not get span text value. thanks

Comment: Then you have an error in your code, or the element does not exist at the point you are trying to select it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `li[data-target=""]` - [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var sample = 'test@gmail.com';
var text = $('ul#list li[data-target="' + sample + '"] span').text();
console.log(text);
```